# Spring data JPA Elastic search and Mongo

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a java class where the @Document object is from elasticsearch package

```
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Document(indexName = "user_data_index", type = "user_data")
    public class User {

        @Id
        private String id;
        private String name;

        public User() {};
    }
```

I would like to use the same object for Spring Data Mongo.

Example:-

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import java.util.List;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
//@Document(indexName = "user_data_index", type = "user_data")
@Document(collection="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public User() {};
}
```

This is so that i can send both data to mongo and elasticsearch during data ingestion. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use at least for one of the `@Document` annotations the full qualified path:

```
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(indexName = "user_data_index", type = "user_data")
@org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document(collection="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public User() {};
}
```